# Blackberry timer not firing TimerTask

Tags: java, blackberry, timer

I am trying to use a time that updates a label every second (so it shows a countdown) but it only 
appears to be "ticking" once and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong!

```
   public class Puzzle extends UiApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle();
    puzzle.enterEventDispatcher();

}

public Puzzle() {


     pushScreen(new PuzzleScreen());
}

}

class PuzzleScreen extends MainScreen {
LabelField timerLabel;
Timer timer;
public static int COUNT = 0;

public PuzzleScreen() {

    //set up puzzle

    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
    add(vfm);
    timerLabel = new LabelField();
    timerLabel.setText("00:20");
    vfm.add(timerLabel);

    StartTimer();

}

void StartTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTick(), 1000);
}
private class TimerTick extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                timerLabel.setText((COUNT++) + "");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong..? All that happens is my label get's set to "0" and then doesn't change. I have put a breakpoint on the run in the timer tick class but I don't see it firing!

Bex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your Timer's schedule() call to

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTick(), 0, 1000);
```

The way you're calling it right now is saying to run it once after a second delay. This way says to run it now and every second. You probably want to use

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTick(), 0, 1000);
```

though, because it will make sure that on average your TimerTask is ran every second rather than with a normal schedule() call that says it will try waiting a second then executing, but it could fall behind if something slows it down. If scheduleAtFixedRate() is delayed, it will make multiple calls quicker than on the 1 second delay so it can "catch up." Take a look at http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: just as you posted that it clicked!! Argh! New to Java and missing my c# bits!! Thank you!

Comment: @jprofitt, i want to call my method only once, so this will be the statement?

 timer.schedule(new TimerTick(), 1000);